# Use jq to sort keys in json using one of the properties

Tags: json, bash, dictionary, key, jq

I need to sort following JSON file by keys with natural order but keys that a listed in the 'required` section should go first, how to do that?

Following command sorts only by keys putting them in natural order:

```
jq --sort-keys . /tmp/source.json > ./tmp/target.json
```

```json
{
   "Request": {
        "properties": {
          "capacity": {
            "$ref": "SubscriptionCapacity"
          },
          "metadata": {
            "$ref": "MeterDefinitionsAndPolicy"
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "avs": {
            "pattern": "standard:v2",
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "data",
          "avs"
        ],
        "type": "object"
      }
}
```

Expected output should be like:

```json
{
   "Request": {
        "properties": {
          "avs": {
            "$ref": "Pricing"
          },
          "data": {
            "type": "string"
          }
          "capacity": {
            "$ref": "SubscriptionCapacity"
          },
          "metadata": {
            "$ref": "MeterDefinitionsAndPolicy"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "data",
          "avs"
        ],
        "type": "object"
      }
}
```

Comment: What's the context here? `jq` does have a limited amount of ability to sort keys, but it's really focused around being able to generate a canonical representation of a given document (so two identical documents have identical hashes). JSON maps aren't considered to _have_ an ordering for semantic purposes -- the maps `{"one": 1, "two": 2}` and `{"two": 2, "one": 1}` are considered identical.

Comment: Now, that doesn't mean you can't possibly do it. One could _certainly_ accomplish this with some code that does fancy manipulation in streaming mode, f/e, but I deeply question its status as anything that might be considered a good idea; the code would be ugly, hard to write and hard to maintain.

Comment: (It might be worth considering how many JSON parsing and generating toolkits don't give you any way to know what the order of keys inside your document's textual representation was at all! If ordering is important, it should be represented in a way that the file format's semantics are guaranteed to preserve, and thus which parsers for that format are required to represent).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a straightforward and fairly efficient approach that takes advantage of the fact that `keys` produces the key names as a sorted array:

```
. as $in
| .Request
| (.required|sort) as $required
| (.properties|keys) as $all
| ($all - $required) as $optional
| .properties as $p
| $in
| .Request.properties = reduce ($required[], $optional[]) as $key ({}; . + {($key): $p[$key]} )
```

---

Note that gojq, the Go implementation of jq, does support `keys` but does not in general respect user-specified ordering of keys within objects.

Answer (score 1):

You *can* do something along the lines of

```
.Request.required as $req
| .Request.properties |= (
    to_entries
    | sort_by(.key)
    | group_by(IN(.key; $req[]) | not)
    | map(from_entries)
    | add
  )
```

```json
{
  "Request": {
    "properties": {
      "avs": {
        "pattern": "standard:v2",
        "type": "string"
      },
      "data": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "capacity": {
        "$ref": "SubscriptionCapacity"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "$ref": "MeterDefinitionsAndPolicy"
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "data",
      "avs"
    ],
    "type": "object"
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/GokgvBzB9I)

but you are not guaranteed that after any follow-up processing the order will stay the same as objects typically *do not have* an order, arrays do.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work as I expected. The only one reason why I am doing that sort is to avoid unnecessary diff before pushing files in github.